# Using images in JComboBox items

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jcombobox

I am trying to build a simple currency converter using `JFrame` using Netbeans and Matisse. I've finished everything else besides one thing. I want to know: How can I put an icon next to the item's name when using `JComboBox` through the Matisse GUI editor?

Comment: 1) This has little if anything to do with your IDE. 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  3) *"..when using Combo-Box not dynamically."*  I understand that up until *"..not dynamically."*.  What do you mean by that? 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: i meant when you build the combobox from drag and drop not coding it manually

Comment: *"i meant when you build the combobox from drag and drop"*  Oh, my bad.  In this case, this **does** relate to your IDE.  I'll edit the post again in a moment to re-add it.

Comment: But further on that note, it seems that the IDE has "made you it's bitch".  I highly recommend learning how to code GUIs without it, before using it.

Comment: i'm just a beginner, started coding about 2 weeks ago

Comment: *"i'm just a beginner"*  All the more reason not to a) Use the GUI designer b) Be coding GUIs at all (they are an advanced subject).

Comment: i've done everything else, i just need to add an icon before the items in combobox. everything works besides that

Comment: I don't know through the GUI but the way it works is that each item of the combo box is a JLabel. JLabels supports displaying images with text, you have to override the ListCellRenderer and put the images in the labels. See the examples on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html